# Cookieの使用に関する同意をとるサイトが増えたのはなぜでしょうか

Tags: cookie

WEBサイトへアクセスすると「最適なエクスペリエンスを提供するためにCookieを使用します」といったメッセージを見かけるようになりました。
法令変更等により増えたのでしょうか？
国内向けのサイトを運営し、トラッキングを行う(アクセス解析をする)にあたり、明示的に同意を取るべきなのでしょうか？
仮にCookieの使用について同意をとらないといけないとき、P3Pでは対応しきれないのでしょうか？

Comment: 確認が遅くなり申し訳ございません。実例を含めての回答、ありがとうございます。法令による対応ということで理解しました。EUに存在する個人情報(IPアドレスも入っているのは要検証)がEU地域外へ持ち出される場合のペナルティが大きいため、特に大企業での対応がなされているということですね。プライバシーポリシーの確認自動化のための P3P (https://www.w3.org/TR/P3P/ ) を使わないのはなぜだろうという点については、 Windows 10以降ではサポートされない (https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-JP/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/mt146424(v=vs.85) ) のと、 ほとんどのウェブブラウザがP3Pを完全にはサポートしていない (https://www.facebook.com/help/327993273962160/ ) ため、使われず、残念な状況になっていると解釈しました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2018年5月25日から適用されることになった、[EU一般データ保護規則](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/EU%E4%B8%80%E8%88%AC%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E4%BF%9D%E8%AD%B7%E8%A6%8F%E5%89%87) (通称 GDPR) の影響かもしれません。EU 向けにサービスを展開する場合に対応が必要だと[言われています](http://www.itmedia.co.jp/enterprise/articles/1806/12/news046.html)。このサイト「スタック・オーバーフロー」は GDPR が原因で利用規約を[変えています](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/21/changes-to-our-privacy-and-data-policies/)。

たとえば日本貿易振興機構が2016年11月に出した「[「EU一般データ保護規則（GDPR）」に関わる実務ハンドブック（入門編）](https://www.jetro.go.jp/world/reports/2016/01/dcfcebc8265a8943.html)」から引用すると、クッキー識別子は個人データであり、「（i）EEA 域内のデータ主体に対して商品やサービスを提供する場合、および（ii）EEA 域内のデータ主体が EEA 域内で行う行動への監視に関連する処理には GDPR が適用されます」とのことです。

※ 法律の解釈をするのはこのサイトの範疇を超えているように思いますので、詳細に関しては専門家の解説や専門の質問サイトをご利用ください。またこの投稿は、対応が必須であると言っているものではございません。

Answer (score 3):

EUクッキー法の影響ではないですかね。

http://business.nikkeibp.co.jp/atcl/report/15/110879/052500827/

気になるようでしたら「EUクッキー法」でググってみてください。